# Gesture recognizer in embedded ViewContainer does not get hit

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

After searching almost 4 days to find a solution for my problem, I'm now asking you, hoping for help.

I have a `UIViewController` with only one `UIViewContainer`. This container will be filled programmatically with a View loaded from a nib file. This last view hast 3 gesture recognizers attached. But none of them are hit.

**The Main View with the ViewContainer**

[image]

**The nib View**

[image]

**Code to load the view.nib into the container**

```
userMasterViewContainer *container = [[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"UserCardView" owner:nil options:nil] lastObject] initWithDelegate:self andUser:user];
[self.viewContainer addSubview:container];
```

**Gesture recognizer code in nib view class**

```
- (void)addGestureRecognizerToPicture:(UIView *)picture
{
    // profile picture gestures
    UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationGesture = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotatePicture:)];
    [picture addGestureRecognizer:rotationGesture];

    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGesture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scalePicture:)];
    [pinchGesture setDelegate:self];
    [picture addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panPicture:)];
    [panGesture setMaximumNumberOfTouches:2];
    [panGesture setDelegate:self];
    [picture addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];

    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}

- (void)rotatePicture:(id)rotateProfilePicture
{

}

- (void)scalePicture:(id)scaleProfilePicture
{   

}

- (void)panPicture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{

}
```

The gestures will be added in viewDidLoad to two `UIImageView`: **Cover Overlay** and **User Photo**

```
[self addGestureRecognizerToPicture:self.backgroundPicture];
```

None of them are working. I hope someone could help me.

Best regards André

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying a few more days, i got the problem solved.
There was a strange combination of Parent-Views catching my user interaction.

I solved it by setting the `userInteractionEnabled` property to `NO` for every view that should not recognize the touches.

```
// setup inactive and active elements for user interactions
self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
self.userPicture.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
self.buttonOverlay.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
self.backgroundPictureOverlay.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
self.userPictureOverlay.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Because there is also a UIButton `Button - Profile` laying over my view. The following code was also needed to prevent him from catching the gesture.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    return touch.view == self.buttonOverlay ? NO : YES;
}
```

In addition, i had to add the following method because i'd like to use these gestures in a simple image editor. With this code i can rotate, scale and pan simultaneously.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```